# Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, betfair

I'm literally using the same code as the official `Betfair Developer` example, the only difference is that I'm putting the `APP_KEY_HERE` and `SESSION_TOKEN` data.

But unlike the site, `Visual Studio Code` is giving me an error and a crash in the terminal.

[image]

Terminal response:

```
line 11
    print json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

https://docs.developer.betfair.com/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Getting+Started

[image]

**What am I missing and what do I need to change to solve this problem?**

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: It seems like VS Code is expecting you to use Python 3. It's not wrong.

Comment: The example was written for Python 2.x. In Python 3 `print` is a function, you have to put the arguments in parentheses.

Comment: Hi mate, Python 3.9.6

Comment: ```print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3))``` missing ```()``` in print function. In python 3.x you have to mention ```()```

Comment: [differences between Python 2 and 3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/important-differences-between-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-with-examples/)

Comment: And now return ```SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing```, any tips on this error?

Comment: Thanks @Sujay solved the error and now appeared what I commented above, could you tell me something about it?

Comment: ```)``` missing. Add one more parenthesis to print function: ```print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3))```

Comment: Oh yes @Sujay , I hadn't paid attention to that either. Your comment solved my problem, please if possible put it as an answer so I can vote as a solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In python 3.x, you have to enclose the arguments in `()`.

```
print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=3))
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in comments `print ""` statement is written for Python 2.x and syntax for this version is not supported in VS Code.

However, you can use `from __future__ import print_function` and start using `print()` with the old interpreter or you can switch to (previously installed) Python 3.x using `CTRL+SHIFT+P` -> `Python:Select interpreter`.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to put this here, even though this is not your problem. Pylance raised this issue because I was missing a `"` character in the preceding line of code. So if you encounter this issue, check if any strings are missing quotation marks in previous lines.